# Setting default value for entity in Filter clause OData .NET

Tags: odata

Is there any way to ensure that certain properties or operators are added into OData expression tree even if they are not specified in URL? For example i want to add some date time constraint everytime when performing search even if user doesn't specify it in URL.

---

Recently i had a problem making request case invariant and i solved it by traversing OData expression tree and adding new function calls into it which seemed a bit of an overkill and i haven't found anything better since then. I am using OData 6.10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some fixed query clause based on user request, you could build up the new query expression using the AND binary operator to combine your fixed clause and user clause.

For example, to add restriction for query products to ReleaseDate newer than 2013, you could do the following:

```
// Fixed clause
var parser = new ODataUriParser(model, new Uri("Products?$filter=ReleaseDate ge 2013-01-01T00:00:00Z", UriKind.Relative));
var fixedExp = parser.ParseFilter().Expression;

// User clause
parser = new ODataUriParser(model, new Uri("Products?$filter=Rating eq 1", UriKind.Relative));
var userExp = parser.ParseFilter().Expression;

var newExp = new BinaryOperatorNode(BinaryOperatorKind.And, fixedExp, userExp);
```

Comment: Well, this simplifies creation of a new query, however is there any way to determine if user made a specific query like 'filter=Rating eq 1' besides traversing the expression tree?